# Ajax.BeginForm - OnSuccess Reload a different area of the page

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, ajax.beginform

I have the following `Ajax.BeginForm()` PartialView which posts to a controller. The form is for adding a new location of a store to a chain. I can write into the database fine, and the `OnSuccess()` method of the `Ajax.BeginForm()` calls as expected with a standard alert.

PartialView:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Stores", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "refresh-panel", OnSuccess = "alert('success')", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    // Form components here
}
```

What I want to do is reload a different Partial View (which is the list of the stores) which is on the same page, thus showing the newly added store. I'd ideally want to do it without refreshing the page, and updating that panel. The panel to be updated has an id of "refresh-panel" around it, so:-

```
<div id="refresh-panel">
    @Html.Partial("_StoresList", Model)
</div>
```

I've tried returning `PartialView("_BrandList");` from the end of the HttpPost controller action but it just replaces the list inside the above `<div>` with a white screen. The controller action to get the list of stores doesn't ever get called, yet `OnSuccess()` still does.

Interestingly as a debug method, I added the following:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("My test button", "_GetStores", "Stores", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "refresh-panel", OnComplete = "BrandLocationsList()" })
```

which does refresh the list of stores as I expect.

Can anyone suggest how to reload that list of stores? Through a JavaScript GET on the OnSuccess() function? Or by returning something different from the `HttpPost` controller?

Thanks in advance!